# How to create a generic wrapper function for saga error handling?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I would like to create a wrapper that would handle the try-catch clauses in my sagas to make them a bit more concise. So far I have the code below, but it's not working.

```
export function* withErrorHandler(fn, errorFn) {
  try {
    fn();
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(errorFn(parseError(e)));
  }
}

export function* logoutSaga() {
  yield withErrorHandler(function*() {
    yield put(logoutRequest());
    yield call(api.logout);
    yield localStorage.clear();
    yield put(logoutSuccess());
  }, logoutFailure);
}
```

Comment: actually `yield fn();` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a wrapper? Just put it in a try/catch block:

```
export function* logoutSaga() {
  try {
    yield put(logoutRequest());
    yield call(api.logout);
    yield localStorage.clear();
    yield put(logoutSuccess());
  } catch(e) {
    yield put(logoutFailure(parseError(e)));
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can eliminate the need to parse errors at all, by wrapping your API functions in a wrapper. For example:

```
class ApiError {
    constructor(err, helpful) {
        this.original = err;
        this.helpful = helpful;
    }
}

const logout = () => { 
    try {
        return axios.post("accounts/logout/");
    } catch (err) {
        throw new ApiError(err, 'There was a problem logging out.');
    }
}
```

Then in your error handling functions, you can check if the thrown error is "`instanceof ApiError`", and display `err.helpful` to the end user. You can take the constructor of `ApiError` even further, parse the original error, and modify `this.helpful` more based on the returned result.

Comment: Mainly to avoid importing `parseError` in every sagas module I have. I'd like to manage parsing errors from one place without additional imports everywhere.

Comment: IMO, put a better error in your api layer (`api.logout`). This way you wont need to call `parseError` at all.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Right now my API calls simply return promises like this export `const logout = () => {
  return axios.post("accounts/logout/");
};`

Answer (score 1):

You pass a generator, not a function so you need to call it properly. You should change your wrapper like this

```
export function* withErrorHandler(fn, errorFn) {
 try {
  yield fn();
 } catch (e) {
...
```